# WPF TextWrapping on white spaces

Tags: wpf, textblock, word-wrap

I am using a TextBlock in WPF, on which I want to use TextWrapping, What I have done in XAML is as follows.

```
<TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.Row="0" Margin="5,5,5,5">
                                <TextBlock.Text>
                                    This is just a test. This is just a test.
                                </TextBlock.Text>
                            </TextBlock>
```

When I run this code it shows output like this

```
This is just a test. Th
is is just a test.
```

But I only want wrapping on white spaces like

```
This is just a test.
This is just a test.
```

I am unable to find why WPF is showing this behavior, I have tried `WrapWithOverflow` and `IsHyphenationEnabled=true` with no success. Please help me out?

Comment: This shouldn't happen. my only guess is that one of its parents is setting a specific property and WPF is projecting it to the TextBlock's properties. try your code on a grid which is put directly in a window and see if the problem still occurs.

Comment: @Bizz, what could be that property? any idea?

Comment: I don't know. but if you check it in its simplest situation, at least you know if it's because of your code of it's related to OS or a .Net build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bizz is right, this shouldn't be the behavior of Text Wrapping, Just a wild guess, are you copy/pasting text from some where to Visual studio? there might be an issue with white spaces in that case, and WPF will wrap your text in wrong way.

Comment: Thanks @madni for your suggestion, I was pasting the text from google translate, and surprisingly it was doing some bad thing with space character, I just replaced the space with actual space and it works fine. :)